Validity of a proof of Cauchy's Integral Theorem using differential forms knowing that f is $C^1$
I'm working on a proof of Cauchy's Integral Theorem using differential forms, and I'd like to verify if my approach is correct. The proof assumes that the function is holomorphic and of class C^1 on a simply connected domain.
So i want to prove that $\int_{\gamma}{f(z)dz = 0}$ for each $\gamma$
Let $f = u+iv$ and $dz = dx+idy$
I can write that:
$$\int_{\gamma}{f(z)dz} = \int_{\gamma}{(u+iv)(dx+idy)} =\int_{\gamma}{(udx-vdy)}+i\int_{\gamma}{(vdx+udy)} $$
My idea is to use this theorem:
$\fbox{$w$ is a exact differential forms $\implies \int_{\gamma}{w dw}$ = 0}$
So if i can prove that the two differential form:
$$
w_1 = udx-vdy\\
w_2 = vdx+udy 
$$
are exact then i have proved the Theorem.
I know that i have to like derive $w_1$ and $w_2$ and later apply the Cauchy-Riemann Equation to show that are equal, but i am not sure how to do it (because the dx,dy confuse me a lot)
Can you show me how to do it?

I know that another way to prove that are exact is to show that if $f$ have antiderivative $F$ then the differential form are exact, is that enough?
